Next Step "weight" variable from Strength Workout in Garmin Connect API
Garmin API provides various data about planned Strength Workout. The Module "Toybox.Activity", specially, provides several classes, such as Info, ProfileInfo, WorkoutIntervalStep, WorkoutStep, WorkoutStepInfo, but neither of them provides the the Weight for the current or the next WorkoutStep.
This information is clearly available somewhere, because the Strength app does make uses of it several time as the images shown.


The thing is how does one get the "weight" variable from the next exercise from a Strength Workout in Garmin Connect API?
My idea is to great a datafield one could see what is the next exercise, how many series, reps and weight to be done in order to effectively setup the gym equipment.
